# Using the equation $ A^{-1} + B^{-1} = (A+B)^{-1} $ to find relations between det(A) and det(B)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

We are given a condition,

$$
A^{-1} + B^{-1} =  (A+B)^{-1}
$$

Further, $|A| =4$ and we are asked to find the value of |B|.

I tried to simplify the LHS 
$$
A^{-1} + B^{-1}= B^{-1}BA^{-1} + B^{-1}AA^{-1}
$$
$$
A^{-1} + B^{-1}= B^{-1}(A+B)A^{-1}
$$

That only lead me to get

$$
|A+B|^2=|A||B|
$$

Am stuck after this. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A,B$ have sizes $n$ with $n > 2$, then it is impossible to determine $|B|$.

If $A,B$ have real entries and $n$ is odd, then it is impossible for $A,B$ to satisfy the given condition.

If $n = 2$ and $A,B$ have real entries, then $|B| = |A|$ must hold.

---

We can write
$$
A^{-1} + B^{-1} = (A + B)^{-1} \iff\\
A(A^{-1} + B^{-1}) = A(A + B)^{-1} \iff\\
AA^{-1} + AB^{-1} = ((A + B)A^{-1})^{-1} \iff\\
I + AB^{-1} = (I + BA^{-1})^{-1}.
$$
Writing $M = BA^{-1}$ (or equivalently $B = MA$) lets us rewrite this as
$$
I + M^{-1} = (I + M)^{-1} \iff\\
(I + M)(I + M^{-1}) = I \iff\\
M + 2I + M^{-1} = I \iff\\
M + I + M^{-1} = 0 \iff\\
M^2 + M + I = 0.
$$
In other words: invertible matrices $A,B$ will satisfy the given equation if and only if $B = MA$ for some (invertible) matrix $M$ with $M^2 + M + I = 0$. $M$ will satisfy this equation if and only if it is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues satisfy $\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1 = 0$. In other words, $M$ will satisfy the equation iff its eigenvalues are all equal to either of the two possibilities $\lambda = -\frac 12 \pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$.

For a $2 \times 2$ real matrix, this implies that $|M| = 1$, so that $|B| = |MA| = |A|\cdot |M| = |A|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The complete problem specifies n is greater than or equal to 2. I suppose they may have neglected the other cases.

Comment: I'm a bit new to eigenvalues. How exactly do you conclude that det(M)=1 from your final statement? EDIT: I got it, from the characteristic equation.

Comment: If $A,B$ are real matrices, then $M = BA^{-1}$ is real. The eigenvalues of $M$ are the solution to the characteristic equation $\det(\lambda I - M) = 0$, which is to say that they are the solutions to a polynomial with real coefficients. So, the eigenvalues of $M$ have to come in complex-conjugate pairs, which means that the eigenvalues are $\lambda_+$ and $\lambda_-$.  So, $\det(M) = \lambda_+ \cdot \lambda_- = 1$.

Comment: @Scilife I see you beat me to it, glad you got it

Comment: Small quibble.  The eigenvalues of $M$ must be those values, but $M$ must also be diagonalizable.  There are non-diagonalizable matrices with only those eigenvalues, but they will not satisfy $M^2+M+I=0$

Comment: @Aaron good point

Answer (score 2):

From $(A+B)(A^{-1}+B^{-1})=I$ you get
$$
I+AB^{-1}+BA^{-1}+I=I \tag{1}
$$
and therefore
$$
I+AB^{-1}+BA^{-1}=0 \tag{2}
$$
Multiply $(2)$ on the right by $A$:
$$
A+AB^{-1}A+B=0 \tag{3}
$$
Multiply $(2)$ on the right by $B$:
$$
B+A+BA^{-1}B=0 \tag{4}
$$
Therefore, comparing $(3)$ and $(4)$,
$$
AB^{-1}A=BA^{-1}B\tag{5}
$$
If $a=\det A$ and $b=\det B$, we get from $(5)$, using Binet's theorem, 
$$
a^2b^{-1}=a^{-1}b^2 \tag{6}
$$
Therefore $b^3=a^3$ and, assuming matrices with real coefficients, $b=a$.

**Notes.**

1. This answer doesn't touch the problem of existence of the given matrices. Other answers give conditions about this.
2. If the matrices are allowed to have complex entries, the only possible conclusion is that $b/a$ is a cube root of unity.

Comment: Thanks, although I wonder why you did not obtain the condition(s) present in some of the other answers.

Comment: @Scilife This proves that *if* such matrices with real entries exist, then they have the same determinant (with complex matrices, the ratio of the determinants is a cube root of unity). It does not touch the problem of existence. Do they exist? Only in very special cases, but that was not the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to MSE.

Your condition is not sufficient to determine an exact value of $\det(B)$. For, take the vector space $\mathbb C$. A linear application $T_c:\mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is just a multiplication for an element $c$ of $\mathbb C$ and the determinant is exactly $c$. So the matrix that represent $T_c$ is just the $1\times 1$ matrix $(c)$.

Take now the linear application $A=T_4$ (that is an application with determinant equal to $4$). Let $B=T_b$; thanks to your condition we have:
\begin{gather}
A^{-1}+B^{-1} = (A+B)^{-1}\\
T_4^{-1}+T_b^{-1} = (T_4+T_b)^{-1}\\
\end{gather}

Using now the fact that $T_c^{-1}=T_{\frac{1}{c}}$ and $T_c + T_d = T_{c+d}$ we obtain the following equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{4+b}
\end{equation}
that has two solutions:
\begin{gather}
b_1 = -2 + 2i\sqrt 3\\
b_2 = -2 - 2i\sqrt 3
\end{gather}
Then, you have two linear application $B_1=T_{b_1}$ and $B_2 = T_{b_2}$ that satisfie the initial condition but they have different determinant $\det(B_1)=b_1\neq b_2=\det (B_2)$. So the initial conditions are not sufficient to determine an exact value of $\det(B)$.